# magento cron malfunction

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I have upgraded from magento 1.8 to 1.9 one month back.

In a module, I have a crontab describing a cron job to execute a function to cancel order automatically after 5 days if the status of the order remains HOLD. Since a year, this was not working and suddenly, few days back it ran and cancelled all the orders satisfying the condition and again it stopped working.

I am not getting like what could be the issue that it worked for the first time ever suddenly.

Is there anyone having any idea on this?

Comment: Can you make sure Magento's `cron.php` (located in the site's root folder) is called in your server's crontab?

Comment: @Julien Lachal: I am not sure how to predict that. Can you mention some trick to see that as because in my server's crontab, I am unable to see any keyword 'cron.php'

Comment: if you have an SSH access to your server, try `cat /etc/crontab` if there is no line about a `cron.php` it's probably why nothing works (cron-wise)

Comment: My issue is somewhat different, this cron never worked but suddenly it worked on 18th Nov and now it is again as it is not working

Comment: @JulienLachal: Is there any possible reason for why this happened that cron worked suddenly after a year and affected my orders?

Comment: Hence my question. If you `cron.php` is never called, it's normal that it never worked. If someone somehow called this script using HTTP then it triggered it once. What this script does is that is parses all the config.xml (in modules) that have a `<cronjob>` node, then add the functions it should call in the DB table `cron_schedule`.

Comment: @JulienLachal: Is it also possible that if someone bymistakely run cron.php from the browser, then that can affect the same? Please let me know

Comment: You are right. When calling it from your server's crontab, you can either call it using the php command or call it via wget, simulating a call from the browser (kind of).

Comment: @JulienLachal: You mean to say, if someone calls www.mydomain.com/cron.php though HTTP, then it should run all the scheduled cron job mentioned under <cronjob> no matter if it configured in server's crontab, did I get you correct?

Comment: Pretty much yes. As I understand it, it'll run all the crons that should have been ran at an earlier date. So is the `cron.php` configured to be ran in your crontab.